# Asymptotic form of the "strange" function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, special-functions

I want to find the asymptotic form of this function

```
exact[t_]:=2^-t ((Binomial[t, 1/2 (-2 + t)] + Binomial[t, (2 + t)/2]) 
(2 + t + (8 (-2 + t) Hypergeometric2F1[3, 2 - t/2, 3 + t/2, -1])/(4 + t)) 
+ \[Pi] Binomial[1 + t, (1 + t)/2] Gamma[(3 + t)/2]
 HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1, 3/2, 3/2, (1 - t)/2}, {1/2, 
  1/2, (3 + t)/2}, -1])
```

I tried:

```
Series[exact[t], {t, Infinity, 0}]
```

But it doesn't produce a result even after a few hours of running.

there is "strange" graphic of this function

```
Plot[exact[t], {t, -20, 1000}]
```

[image]

Comment: Mathematica does not know how to expand `Hypergeometric2F1[3, 2 - t/2, 3 + t/2, -1]` at `t` near `Infinity`, so it is not expected to find the asymptotic behavior of your `exact`.  Also, it seems that `HypergeometricPFQRegularized` is what causes excessive computation time.

Answer (score 5):

Taking into account the remark of @vito in the comment, I suggest to take the correct formulas of the simple one-dimensional random walk and calculate the mean square deviation as a function of time.

The probability that the walker gets at the point n at time t is given by

```
p[n_, t_] := 1/2^t Binomial[t, (t + n)/2]
```

The normalization can be checked by this sum

```
Sum[p[n, t], {n, -t, t, 2}]

(* Out[16]= 1 *)
```

Notice that, the sum differs from the sum in the OP in these two aspects: the sum is over a finite number of terms from - t to + t, and it jumps in steps of two.

Higher moments are (Simplify takes care that t assumes integer values)

```
m[k_] := Simplify[Sum[n^k p[n, t], {n, -t, t, 2}], t \[Element] Integers]

m[1]

(* Out[39]= 0 *)
```

And the moment in question is

```
m[2]

(* Out[40]= t *)
```

As expected it is equal to the time t, i.e. the numer of steps taken.

**EDIT**

We can calculate and identify a general moment.
The generating function of the moments `Expectation( Exp[n x])` is

```
g[x_, t_] := Cosh[x]^t
```

Hence the moments are

```
m[k_] := D[g[x, t], {x, k}] /. x -> 0
```

The first few are

```
tb = Table[m[k], {k, 0, 10, 2}] // Expand

(* Out[30]= 
{1, t, -2 t + 3 t^2, 
 16 t - 30 t^2 + 15 t^3, -272 t + 588 t^2 - 420 t^3 + 105 t^4, 
 7936 t - 18960 t^2 + 16380 t^3 - 6300 t^4 + 945 t^5}
*)
```

These polynomials in t are related to the sequence

```
Flatten[List @@@ tb] /. t -> 1

(* Out[37]= {1, 1, -2, 3, 16, -30, 15, -272, 588, -420, 105, 7936, -18960, 16380, -6300, 945}
*)
```

which is listed in https://oeis.org/A085734

Answer (score 3):

The `exact` function can be simplified

```
exact[t_] = 
 2^-t ((Binomial[t, 1/2 (-2 + t)] + Binomial[t, (2 + t)/2]) (2 + 
         t + (8 (-2 + t) Hypergeometric2F1[3, 2 - t/2, 3 + t/2, -1])/(4 + 
            t)) + \[Pi] Binomial[
        1 + t, (1 + t)/2] Gamma[(3 + t)/2] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1, 
         3/2, 3/2, (1 - t)/2}, {1/2, 1/2, (3 + t)/2}, -1]) //
   FunctionExpand // FullSimplify

(*  t + (4*Gamma[(3 + t)/2]*
        ((4 + t)*(2 + 3*t) + 
           2*(-2 + t)*t*Hypergeometric2F1[
               1, 2 - t/2, (6 + t)/2, -1]))/
     (Sqrt[Pi]*(1 + t)*(2 + t)*
        (4 + t)*Gamma[t/2])  *)
```

The limit of the `exact` function exists at `t = 0`

```
exact[0] = exact[0.] = Limit[exact[t], t -> 0]

(*  0  *)
```

The first term of the series expansion does not really simplify the expression and its limit does not exist at `t = 0`

```
approx[t_] = Series[exact[t], {t, Infinity, 0}] // Normal // FullSimplify

(*  (1/(32*Sqrt[Pi]))*((1/t)^(3/2)*
      ((32*Sqrt[Pi])/(1/t)^(5/2) + 
         Sqrt[2]*(291 + 
              8*t*(-19 + 12*t)) + 
         2*Sqrt[2]*(1345 + 
              8*t*(-33 + 4*t))*
           Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2 - t/2, 
             (6 + t)/2, -1]))  *)

Limit[approx[t], t -> 0]

(*  ∞  *)
```

To avoid loss of precision in the `Plot` set a `WorkingPrecision` to force use of arbitrary precision rather than machine precision in the calculations.

```
Plot[{exact[t], approx[t]}, {t, -20, 1000},
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thick],
   Directive[Red, AbsoluteDashing[{15, 10}]]},
 WorkingPrecision -> 20,
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{approx[t] - exact[t]}, {t, 200, 2000},
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: But in my book, answer is $t$.  $\sqrt{\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{2^t}\binom{t}{\frac{t+n}{2}}}=\sqrt{t}$. I evaluate this infinite series and I gave the function "exact[t]"

Comment: "my book" - can you show this book to us, @vito?

Comment: @vito - Or show us the Mathematica commands that you used to evaluate the series shown in your comment.

Comment: @J.M. [Quantum Walks and Search Algorithms ](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1k4afz4v2xldl63/Quantum%20Walks%20and%20Search%20Algorithms.pdf?dl=0) page 19. equation 3.3. thanks